# Unregister eventprocessor when nothing received for a while

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I implemented ieventprocessor (according to this tutorial:[EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host) and registered it to eventprocessorhost. Is there any possibility to unregister it in a case of inactivity? For example if no message was received in last 10 minutes, I would like to close the connection. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes this is possible by calling the unregister method when you detect inactivity. How to detect that is up to you. But I wonder what you will do to make it listen again if there are new messages.

Comment: @PeterBons, can you post a detailed answer? so it can help others.